# Some fonts on Chrome on Windows 10 are massive - how to fix?

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, fonts

Some fonts on Chrome on Windows 10 are extremely large. Most are fine, but occasionally, I see a font that looks three or four times as big as it should be. For example, the tooltip on mouseover on a Chrome tab:

[image: large tooltip font in Chrome]

Likewise, I have some apps which have extremely small font sizes. I can't find an example right now.

How do I identify where this problem is coming from? My font size is set to 100%, and my resolution on external monitor is 1920x1200, and my laptop monitor is 3200x1800.

Even here on Stackexchange, the scroll bars are huge:

[image: Huge scrollbars on stackexchange]

It's very odd, and seems as if one particular default font is set to 400% of normal size or something?

Any tips?

Comment: If you go to Personalize and change theme to any other theme, does that fix your problem or alter it in any way?

Comment: I changed theme from "Dell" to "Microsoft", and nothing changed. I didn't log out or restart though. However, I also tested same thing in Superuser with MS Edge, and there's no problem, which makes me think it could be a Chrome issue (except that some Explorer dialogue boxes - started from within Chrome - also have odd font sizes)

Comment: Sounds like a DPI issue, which requires a logout and login to change. You really need to do that to be absolutely sure. Changing DPI without logout and login will make changes, but not everywhere, and that is exactly your symptom.

Comment: What's dpi (dots per inch?) and where do you change it?

Comment: This is most likely due to the difference in resolution between your laptop's display and the external monitor:

https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/why-is-my-1080p-external-monitor-blurry-w-my-1800p-laptop-629106/

Comment: Please first log out and in after changing the theme to verify if this changes the problem or not.

Comment: It's hard to know which thing fixed it, but it's now fixed after a reboot, and changing the theme and perhaps other items. I wasn't very disciplined....